# Smooth zooming through the canvas

Tags: javascript, scroll, fabricjs, smoothing

I have a zooming feature in my fabricjs app. The that runs zoom is just very similar to this: http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-5

```
canvas.on('mouse:wheel', function(opt) {
  var delta = opt.e.deltaY;
  var zoom = canvas.getZoom();
  zoom *= 0.999 ** delta;
  if (zoom > 20) zoom = 20;
  if (zoom < 0.01) zoom = 0.01;
//  canvas.zoomToPoint({ x: opt.e.offsetX, y: opt.e.offsetY }, zoom); commented because I run canvas.zoomToPoint in main canvas update function, not just inside handler
  this.zoom = zoom;
  opt.e.preventDefault();
  opt.e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Now I would like to program a smooth zooming on mouse wheel - so that it zooms like here: https://mudin.github.io/indoorjs but I completely don't know where to start.
I feel like I need to debounce somehow the handler for mouse wheel, because for now it happens whenever you wheel the mouse - is this the right direction? How to accomplish something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is usefull. There is an eventlistener for the wheel event and then I set the scale of the element and control the scaling in CSS.

```js
var box = document.querySelector('#box');

box.scale = 1; // initial scale

box.addEventListener('wheel', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  var deltaScale = (e.deltaY > 0) ? .1 : -.1;
  e.target.scale = e.target.scale + deltaScale;
  e.target.style.transform = `scale(${e.target.scale})`;
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

#box {
  border: thin solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still wondering how to implement smooth zooming in Fabric.js

First you need to register a change event for the mouse wheel:
(keeping track of the values in a `Mouse` object)

```
canvas.on('mouse:wheel', (e) => {
        Mouse.x = e.e.offsetX;
        Mouse.y = e.e.offsetY;
        Mouse.w += e.e.wheelDelta;
        return false;
    });
```

Then you need to call this function in your render loop when `Mouse.w !== 0`:

```
let targetZoomLevel = canvas.getZoom();
let isAnimationRunning = false;
let abort = false;

// Call this function in your render loop if Mouse.W != 0
function zoom() {
    // mousewheel value changed: abort animation if it's running
    abort = isAnimationRunning;

    // get current zoom level
    let curZoom = canvas.getZoom();

    // Add mousewheel delta to target zoom level
    targetZoomLevel += Mouse.w / 2000;

    // Animate the zoom if smooth zooming is enabled
    fabric.util.animate({
        startValue: curZoom,
        endValue: targetZoomLevel,
        // Set this value to your liking
        duration: 500,
        easing: fabric.util.ease.easeOutQuad,
        onChange: (newZoomValue) => {
            isAnimationRunning = true;
            // Zoom to mouse pointer location
            canvas.zoomToPoint({
                x: Mouse.x,
                y: Mouse.y
            }, newZoomValue);
            // call canvas.renderAll here
        },
        onComplete: () => {
            isAnimationRunning = false;
        },
        abort: () => {
            // The animation aborts if this function returns true
            let abortValue = abort;

            if (abortValue == true) {
                abort = false;
            }

            return abortValue;
        }
    });
}
```

It aborts the animation when the mousewheel value changes and adds the value to a zoom target